# Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min.js' on HEROKU

Tags: angular, sockets, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Mean App with socket on Heroku. App works perferctly on localhost but when I try to push it to Heroku it says me :

> Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min.js'

Thanks in advance
PS : Sorry for my english